# Parallel colouring to minimize collisions?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, research

I have a graph in which there is a set of leader vertices $L$. There is no edge between any pair of leader vertices. Each leader vertex $u$ has a *common* set of colours $C$ and a set of neighbour vertices $N(u)$. A leader vertex is oblivious of the decisions of other leader vertices. Each leader vertex picks a colour for each of its neighbours. A leader knows its neighbours, the available colours, and the number of leaders.

Let $w$ be a common neighbour for leader vertices $u$ and $v$, i.e., $w \in N(u)\cap N(v)$. If the leader vertices $u$ and $v$ assign the same colour for $w$, a collision occurs.

I would like to find an algorithm that is executed at each leader vertex independently and assigns a unique colour to each one of its neighbours such that the number of collisions is as small as possible.

The context of this problem is from frequency assignments in a distributed wireless sensor network, where each node that can communicate (it is a neighbour) with more than one leader cannot do so using the same frequency.

This problem is probably studied before. Because I have little graph-theory backgrounds, I hope some help from graph-theory specialists? At least, can you point me to any reference I should read?

For now, I am looking for "Parallel graph colouring", "Leader colouring", but I am a little lost.

Comment: Each leader vertex only picks a single neighboring vertex to assign a color to, and the rest don't have any color assigned (at least not by that leader)?  What is known to the leader vertex?  Does it have visibility of the whole graph?  Or, put it another way, if you want an algorithm, what are the inputs to the algorithm and the desired outputs?  If every leader knows the entire graph, what is the meaning of each leader working "independently"?  Any coordinated strategy can be converted into an "independent" strategy.

Comment: Can you share anything about the context in which you encountered this task, or the motivation?

Comment: Each leader vertex picks a colour for each of its neighbour. A leader knows its neighbours, the available colours, and the number of leaders. The context is from frequency assignments in a distributed wireless sensor network, where each node that can communicate (it is a neighbour) with more than one leader cannot do so using the same frequency.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information and correct the errors ("to one of its neighbors...").  What does it mean to "know its neighbors"?  Does it know a unique ID for each of its neighbors? Does it have a way to identify its neighbors, or does it only know the number of neighbors?